# I have an error with my php trigger#1064 -check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have written Upate trigger on user in trigger I written Update query to update login table

```
CREATE trigger auou AFTER update ON  `user` 
FOR each
ROW 
BEGIN 
update login
set `user`='new.user_id',`password`='new.password'
where  `user`='new.user_id';
```

Comment: Remove the quotes before and after `new.user_id` and Don't forget the `END;`

Comment: what's the full error message?

Comment: CREATE trigger auou AFTER UPDATE ON  `user` FOR each ROW BEGIN UPDATE login SET  `user` =  'new.user_id',
`password` =  'new.password' WHERE  `user` = new.user_id;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7